# sql server agent start disabled (grayed out)

Tags: sql, installation

I've just built a new dev machine and I can't get SQL Server Agent working. What I've done so far:

1. Install VS 2010 (I think this installed an express version of SQL Server)
2. Install SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition.

I'm not sure if I did something wrong in step 2.  All I want is a fully working version of SQL Server with SQL Server Agent running and no limitation on the amount of data I can store (I will need more than 10GB).

Currently, in SSMS I have the following instance: ./SQLEXPRESS.  I thought that during step 2, this would have been upgraded, but it doesn't seem so.

Can anyone help?

**Note: I ended up resolving this by uninstalling everything that had "SQL Server" in it in Control Panel > Programs and Features.  I then reinstalled from scratch.**

Answer (score 2):

The agent account is disabled.  If you aren't able to enable it through configuration manager, try enabling it through services.  After its enabled, try starting the serivce.  If you still have issues starting the agent, try changing the account the service is running under. There may also be an issue with the account that the SQL Server service is running under.  Trying changing the SQL Server service account and restarting it.  The agent should then start up successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I ended up resolving this by uninstalling everything that had "SQL Server" in it in Control Panel > Programs and Features. I then reinstalled from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You have two installations, with two named instances. The Express named SQLEXPRESS and the developer edition named MSSQLSERVER (unless you changed this during install). connect to .\MSSQLSERVER and see, it should be there available to be started.

SQL Server Express does not ship with the SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Thanks, I tried .\MSSQLSERVER and it didn't work.  It also doesn't appear in my list of Server names when I go to connect. Is the next step to re-install?  And if so, how do I get rid of Express and install a clean version of SQL Server?

Comment: Alternatively, how do I go about creating a new instance?

Comment: I ended up resolving this by uninstalling everything that had "SQL Server" in it in Control Panel > Programs and Features.  I then reinstalled from scratch.